# JavaScript: Discord.js Error with !kick command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have been upgrading all my previous commands to have a response with embeds instead of a normal response.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client({ws: {intents: Discord.Intents.ALL}});

exports.run = async (bot,message,args) => {
let member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])
let reason = args.slice(1).join(' ');

let embed1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`You Do Not Have The Permissions For This Command!`)
    .setDescription(`<@!${message.member.user.id}> you are not an Admin`)
    .setColor('#eeff00')
    .setFooter(`Bot is maintained by  BLADEZ#7296`)
let embed2 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`InValid User`)
    .setDescription(`<@!${message.member.user.id}> please give a valid User \n **Remember** !kick [@User] [reason]`)
    .setColor('#eeff00')
    .setFooter(`Bot is maintained by  BLADEZ#7296`)
let embed3 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`Kick Unsuccessful`)
    .setDescription(`<@!${message.member.user.id}> you can not kick this person!`)
    .setColor('#eeff00')
    .setFooter(`Bot is maintained by  BLADEZ#7296`)
let embed4 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`Kick Successful`)
    .setDescription(`**<@!${member.user.id}>** has been **kicked** for **${reason}** by **<@!${message.author.id}>**`)
    .setColor('#eeff00')
    .setFooter(`Bot is maintained by  BLADEZ#7296`)

    
    if(!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_ROLES")) return message.channel.send(embed1)
    
    if(member) return message.channel.send(embed2)
   
    if(member.roles.highest.position > message.member.roles.highest.position) return message.channel.send (embed3)
    if(!reason) {reason = 'No reason given'}
    member.kick(reason)
    message.channel.send(embed4);
    console.log(`**${member.user.tag}** has been kicked for ${reason} by ${message.author.tag}`)
}

exports.help = {
    name: 'kick'
}
```

So this is the code I use which I haven't changed only added embeds.^

[image]

But I get this error ^. Kick still works just get an error if I don't include a user after `!kick`.

Comment: Hey BLADEZ, could you please share the stacktrace as text instead of linking a picture? This will help your answer be more searchable by other users which may have your same issue :) as a wild guess, it seems that either `member` or `message.member` is undefined, which explains the error. You should probably try to do some debugging on your own (ie. understand which one is undefined and _why_ it is undefined - might simply be that there is no property `message.member` and it should be `member` instead!) to understand if you can fix the issue on your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to use `member.user.id`, but if there is no member mentioned, `member` will be `undefined`.

You don't actually need to create all these embeds if you will only use one of them. Create them inside the if statements, when you're sure the values are available.

It's enough to only declare the embed and just update it.

```js
exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
  let member =
    message.mentions.members.first() ||
    message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
  let reason = args.slice(1).join(' ');

  let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#eeff00')
    .setFooter(`Bot is maintained by  BLADEZ#7296`);

  if (!message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_ROLES')) {
    embed
      .setTitle(`You Do Not Have The Permissions For This Command!`)
      .setDescription(`<@!${message.member.user.id}> you are not an Admin`);

    return message.channel.send(embed);
  }

  // are you sure you want to check if member exists?
  // if (member) should be if (!member)
  if (!member) {
    embed
      .setTitle(`InValid User`)
      .setDescription(
        `<@!${message.member.user.id}> please give a valid User \n **Remember** !kick [@User] [reason]`,
      );
    return message.channel.send(embed);
  }

  if (member.roles.highest.position > message.member.roles.highest.position) {
    embed
      .setTitle(`Kick Unsuccessful`)
      .setDescription(
        `<@!${message.member.user.id}> you can not kick this person!`,
      );
    return message.channel.send(embed);
  }

  embed
    .setTitle(`Kick Successful`)
    .setDescription(
      `**<@!${member.user.id}>** has been **kicked** for **${reason}** by **<@!${message.author.id}>**`,
    );

  if (!reason) {
    reason = 'No reason given';
  }

  member.kick(reason);
  message.channel.send(embed);
  console.log(
    `**${member.user.tag}** has been kicked for ${reason} by ${message.author.tag}`,
  );
};
```

It seems to be working as expected:

[image]